# react-route-dom v6 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Tags: javascript, react-router-dom

I am having trouble passing state to the component destination specified in Navigate.

```json
    "react": "~18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
```

send `${address}` valiable

- from `Wallet.js`

```js
    import { useNavigate } from "react-route-dom";

    const Wallet = ({ address, amount, symbol, destroy }) => {
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        return (
            <div>
                <button>
                    onClick={() =>
                    navigate("/booked", { state: { address: `${address}` } })
                    }
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

- to `RoomManagement.js`

```js
    import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

    const RoomManagement = () => {
        const { location } = useLocation();
        console.log("get address: ", location);
    }
```

But in console:

[image]

I tried to access, but it gives me an error.:

[image]

What would need to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

`location` ***is*** the object returned from the `useLocation` hook. `state` would then be destructured from `location`.

Examples:

```
const RoomManagement = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("get address: ", location.state?.address);
  }, [location]);

  ...
}
```

or

```
const RoomManagement = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("get address: ", state?.address);
  }, [state]);

  ...
}
```